# Sending an array from javascript to Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, django

I have an array of objects in javascript.
`Arr = [0: {k;v}, 1: {k,v}]` etc etc... with a lot of fields in them.

I'm having trouble sending them to Django.

I've tried doing `JSON.stringify` and sending it to django and retrieving with both `getlist` and `get`.

The problem is I get a list with two dictionaries inside but I cannot figure out how to iterate through the list.

Current code is sending the array to Django this way:

```
{'data[]': JSON.stringify(arr)}
```

And in Django:

```
req = request.POST.getlist('data[]', None)
```

What I get back when I print the statement is:

`[ { dict of key, value pairs }, { dict of key value pairs }]`

I cannot figure out how to iterate through the list of dictionaries and retrieve the key value pairs and keep them as separate.

Comment: `[0: {k;v}, 1: {k,v}]`. This is not a valid list, it look like a dict. Did you mean `[{0: {k;v}, 1: {k,v}}, ...]` ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but are you sending the string-ified list? Then Django receives a string that you need to "unpack" with `json.loads()` to get a Python `list` object.

Comment: Is JSON.stringify not needed? I just changed the getlist to get and did a json.loads on it, the results are about the same though. Maybe this will be easier to iterate through...

Comment: That was it. I have it now. Thank you guys. Now I can iterate through it perfectly with two loops. One for the list and one for each dict.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with help from the comments.

Instead of using .getlist I used .get and wrapped it in json.loads().

From there I was able to look through this way:

```
req = json.loads( request.POST.get('data[]', None) )

for each_row in req:
    for k, v in each_row.items():
        print(k, v)
```